# How can I parse String to (int * int) tuple in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I have a string something like this `"3,4\r\n"`, and I want to convert them into a tuple i.e `(3,4)`.

How can we achieve this in SML ?

The reason why I'm getting a string value is because I'm reading a file which returns strings like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a simple parser to achieve that. An appropriate function to parse integers is already available in the library as [`Int.scan`](http://standardml.org/Basis/integer.html#SIG%3aINTEGER.scan%3aVAL) (along with friends for other types), but you have to write the rest yourself. For example:

```
(* scanLine : (char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> (int * int, 's) StringCvt.reader *)
fun scanLine getc stream =
    case Int.scan StringCvt.DEC getc stream
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (x1, stream') =>
    case getc stream'
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (c1, stream'') =>
    if c1 <> #"," then NONE else
    case Int.scan StringCvt.DEC getc stream''
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (x2, stream''') => 
    case getc stream'''
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (c2, stream'''') =>
    if c2 <> #"\n" then NONE else
    SOME ((x1, x2), stream'''')
```

And then, to parse all lines:

```
(* scanList : ((char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> ('a, 's) StringCvt.reader) -> (char, 's)  StringCvt.reader -> ('a list, 's) StringCvt.reader *)
fun scanList scanElem getc stream =
    case scanElem getc stream
      of NONE => SOME ([], stream)
       | SOME (x, stream') =>
    case scanList scanElem getc stream'
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (xs, stream'') => SOME (x::xs, stream'')
```

To use it, for example:

```
val test = "4,5\n2,3\n"
val result = StringCvt.scanString (scanList scanLine) test
(* val result : (int * int) list = [(4, 5), (2, 3)] *)
```

As you can see, the code is a bit repetitive. To get rid of all the matching of option types you could write a few basic *parser combinators*:

```
(* scanCharExpect : char -> (char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> (char, 's) StringCvt.reader *)
fun scanCharExpect expect getc stream =
    case getc stream
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (c, stream') =>
         if c = expect then SOME (c, stream') else NONE

(* scanSeq : ((char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> ('a, 's) StringCvt.reader) * ((char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> ('b, 's) StringCvt.reader) -> (char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> ('a * 'b, 's) StringCvt.reader *)
fun scanSeq (scan1, scan2) getc stream =
    case scan1 getc stream
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (x1, stream') =>
    case scan2 getc stream'
      of NONE => NONE
       | SOME (x2, stream'') => SOME ((x1, x2), stream'')

fun scanSeqL (scan1, scan2) getc stream =
    Option.map (fn ((x, _), stream) => (x, stream)) (scanSeq (scan1, scan2) getc stream)
fun scanSeqR (scan1, scan2) getc stream =
    Option.map (fn ((_, x), stream) => (x, stream)) (scanSeq (scan1, scan2) getc stream)

(* scanLine : (char, 's) StringCvt.reader -> (int * int, 's) StringCvt.reader *)
fun scanLine getc stream =
    scanSeq (
        scanSeqL (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC, scanCharExpect #","),
        scanSeqL (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC, scanCharExpect #"\n")
    ) getc stream
```

There are a lot more cool abstractions you can build along these lines, especially when defining your own infix operators. But I'll leave it at that.

You might also want to handle white space between tokens. The [`StringCvt.skipWS`](http://standardml.org/Basis/string-cvt.html#SIG%3aSTRING_CVT) reader is readily available in the lib for that, just insert it in the right places.

Comment: Using higher-order functions to manipulate resources (such as open files) is a little bit nerve-wracking, because you never really know when an exception will be thrown, in which case it is not clear that the resource will not leak. Is there a more first-order alternative to doing this?

Comment: @pyon, if you follow the natural style above where all functions are defined such that computation only happens in fully applied bodies, then exceptions shouldn't be an issue more than elsewhere. Of course, it would be nice to have an effect system that checks that... Either way, the only way to make parsing first-order is to not have polymorphic parsing functions.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a crude example of how this can be done

```
fun toPair s =
    let
      val s' = String.substring(s, 0, size s-2)
    in
      List.mapPartial Int.fromString (String.tokens (fn c => c = #",") s')
    end
```

However note that mapPartial discards any thing that can't be converted to an integer (when `Int.fromString` returns `NONE`), and that it is assumed that the string always contains `\r\n`, as the last two characters is removed by taking the substring.

**Update**

Obviously the answer by Rossberg is the correct way of doing it. However depending on the task at hand this may still serve as an example of a quick and stupid way of doing it.

Comment: Nice hack. But it throws me this error: `Error: unbound variable or constructor: mapPartial.` But If I do List.mapPartial I get List instead of tuple.

Comment: True, I opened the list module when testing something else, my mistake.

Comment: Anyway, I can pattern match and convert them to tuple, not a big deal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward way to extract all of the unsigned integers from a string and return them in a list (converting the list to a tuple is left as an exercise for the reader).

```
fun ints_from_str str =
  List.mapPartial
    Int.fromString
    (String.tokens (not o Char.isDigit) str);

ints_from_str " foo 1, bar:22? and 333___  ";

(* val it = [1,22,333] : int list *)
```

Answer (score -1):

Following should achieve this.

```
 exception MyError

 fun convert(s) = 
   case String.explode(s) of
        x::','::y::_ => (x,y)
       | _ => raise MyError
```

PS - did not have access to an SML interpreter at work. So may need slight changes.

Comment: Even when you do like this, the returned tuple will contain x and y as char only.

Comment: This only works if both numbers will be exactly one digit long.