# SMLNJ Parse list of strings into list of tuples with multiple datatypes

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have a list of strings that I would like to parse into a list of tuples.

more specifically:

```
val strlist = ["1, 2, 3, 'hello', 4, 5, false, 6, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]",
               "6, 1, 3, 'world', 4, 5, true, 4, [1, 2], [4, 7, 5]",
               . . .] : string list
```

into

```
val tuplist = [(1, 2, 3, "hello", 4, 5, false, 6, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]),
               (6, 1, 3, "world", 4, 5, true, 4, [1, 2], [4, 7, 5]),
               . . .] : (int * int * int * string * int * int * bool * int * int list * int list) list
```

Every list element has the same format.

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far? Show us you've put some effort in, and we'll help you with a **specific** problem you've encountered. That said, I doubt this is possible as such a function would *require its type to change at run-time* (unless you know all the strings have that format, in which case mention it in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here:
[How can I parse String to (int * int) tuple in SML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750444/how-can-i-parse-string-to-int-int-tuple-in-sml)

Though i would just use String.fields to get out the strings, glue the list strings with ^, and convert the formats. I would just need an extra function to convert the list string into the sublist. Bit tedious, but not difficult.